# angular2-jwt using tokenNotExpired() in Promise/Observable?

Tags: angular, jwt, observable

I got an AuthService in my angular 2 app which provides following public method:

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  /* check if id_token is expired or not */
  return tokenNotExpired();
}
```

In the template I can check if a user is authenticated with

```
<button [routerLink]="['/signup']"
        *ngIf="!auth.isAuthenticated()">
  Sign Up
</button>
```

My problem is if the user is signed out this works fine. If the user navigates to route "/signup" and signs in `auth0.client.login()` runs and signs the user in. The templates notices the change due to angular change detection?! **Works fine so far.**

But if I use the function `isAuthenticated()` inside another method of AuthService which is called in certain components:

```
public isAuthorized(): Promise<boolean> {

  return new Promise(resolve => {

    if(!this.isAuthenticated()) {
      resolve(false);
    }

    ... further logic

  }
}
```

This function does not know of the "sign in" change. Or put another way needs to update, because isAuthenticated now changes to returning `true` instead of `false` before the sign in.

In the components I need to "observe" the `isAuthenticated()` state and run `isAuthorized()` again if it changes. How could I get this to work?

An example would be awesome since I tried to get this to work since hours.

Answer (score 0):

take a **boolean** type variable and check it with the ** isAuthenticated()** function.

Comment: I don't get this

Comment: Make a variable with boolean data type and check with the function. Means, check if the type is false or true. You are using the function as boolean here. Instead of function use variable. and inside function return the variable value by checking

Comment: Where should I make a boolean variable and check with which function? You mean something like `let isAuthenticated: boolean = tokenNotExpired()` ? Inside which function?